# Jquery array pass 'All' text until values entered and replace text with 'All' if they are cleared down again

Tags: jquery

I am stuck with a Jquery loop.

Currently I have two checkbox groups which loads the seperate array of data and passes the values of the checkboxes through to the list1 or list2 div's respectively.

I want to pass 'All' text inside either list1 or list2 until checkbox values are selected. When checkbox values are selected it'll clear the text 'All' and show the checkbox values. If they are cleared down then All should re-appear in the div.

Any ideas, I was thinking the loop might need to change to include an if and else statement but I was getting stuck with reloading the data into the divs.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x6z2bkt7/

```
$(document).on('change', '.filterTag .ais-refinement-list__checkbox', 
function() {
getValueUsingParentTag();
});


function getValueUsingParentTag() {
$('[id^="list"]').empty(); // empty divs
$('.filterTag .ais-refinement-list__checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, ele) {
    var target2 = $(this).closest('.filterTag').data('filter');
    $(target2).html(function(idx, html) {
        return html.length == 0 ? ele.value : html + ', ' + ele.value;
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Can you explain, since you have two sets of checkboxes, when should the "All" exactly appear? What means *`"I want to pass 'All' text inside either list1 or list2"`*? Pass? Like how and where exactly?

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me. So I want the all text to appear in both list1 and list2 divs from the start. If the List 1 however has a checkbox selection then 'All' would be replaced with whatever checkbox values are selected. The list2 runs independently so again if you then go to list2 by default you would expect to see all and then when you select a checkbox the value would change to the checkbox value. Then if you clear the checkbox selections you'd expect all to go back into the respective list1 or list2 divs. Does this help?

Comment: Why should the *All* text appear *from the start* - if no checkboxes are actually checked initially?

Comment: Because basically no filters are then being set so it's loading all results and then once the checkboxes are selected this is where the filters start running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it.
A function that maps over the values of the `:checked` checkboxes or returns `"All"` as fallback - if the mapped (and joined) string is empty.

<sub>P.S: removed all the unnecessary classes from this demo to keep things clean - You can use the same JS without changes on your markup</sub>

```js
function updateFilterList() {

  $('[data-filter]').attr('data-filter', function(i, v) {
     $(v).text( $(":checked", this).get().map(el => el.value).join(" ") || "All");
  });

}

// Do on checkbox change
$(document).on('change', '[data-filter] :checkbox', updateFilterList);

// Do on DOM ready
updateFilterList();
```

```html
<h2>List 1</h2>
<div data-filter="#list1">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox Group 1 Checkbox 1">
      <span>Checkbox Group 1 Checkbox 1</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox Group 1 Checkbox 2">
      <span>Checkbox Group 1 Checkbox 2</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="list1"></div>

<h2>List 2</h2>
<div data-filter="#list2">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox Group 2 Checkbox 1">
      <span>Checkbox Group 2 Checkbox 1</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox Group 2 Checkbox 2">
      <span>Checkbox Group 2 Checkbox 2</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="list2"></div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Roko, thank you for taking a look at this but it's not right sadly. I need it to stick with my fiddle structure tree due to this being a 3rd party extension that puts these classes in. I am not seeing the 'ALL' text in the list1 or list2 divs at the moment when no checkboxes have been selected, doesn't seem any different unless there is a bug?

Comment: @Bradley regarding bugs, it helps to open the Developer Console and read our the eventual errors you have (if any) - or state in a comment *"no errors in console"* - so I can reject that as a possible cause.

Comment: Oooo! This is really impressive. I like how clean and minimal it is.

Comment: @Bradley here's a fiddle example with the above JS and your exact HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/x6z2bkt7/87/

Comment: You've done a really great job on this, thank you very much!

Comment: @Bradley kind words! Thanks, happy coding